# Jquery onclick function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, onclick

I have this function in my global.js file, code below:

```
$("a.dialog-page").click(function(event) {

          event.preventDefault();
          $this = $(this);

          var URL     = $(this).attr('href');
          var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialog');
          var dialogOptions = {

                        width: 500,
                        height: 200,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function(event, ui){
                            $('#dialog').empty(); 
                       }
          };

    if(dialogbox==null) {
        $this.after("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");

    }

    jQuery('#dialog').load(URL + " #content").dialog(dialogOptions);

});
```

I have dynamically generated HTML with the following markup:

```
<div id="dynamic-id">
  <a class="dialog-page" href="/test/test.php">Link to test</a>
</div>
```

Here is the click trigger for that link coming from my local.js file:

```
  $('#dynamic-id').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
    event.preventDefault;
  });
```

The problem is when clicking on the link, it is not calling ("a.dialog-page").click event which would load up my modal window.

How can I address this?

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: All your event handler code should be inside the code you call the "click trigger" instead of the first function.

Comment: You have 2 click handlers for the same 'a.dialog-page' selector! Just use one as suggested by @Pointy.

Comment: @Pointy what do you mean by the click trigger. Are you referring to putting the code within $('#dynamic-id').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
    // code in here
  });

Answer (score 1):

Since `#dynamic-id` is also generated dynamically, you need to use other static parent like `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
    event.preventDefault;
});
```

Comment: tried this as well and unfortunately, doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

Element **#dynamic-id** is also generated dynamically.

So when you are binding the element the element **#dynamic-id** doesnot exist in DOM while you are binding the event to it .

TO fix this you can use as follows

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
    alert("Link clicked");
    event.preventDefault;
});
```

Comment: i have tried this, but it doesn't work. The alert doesn't show and it just goes to the test.php page

Comment: Are you using both the click events ?
$("a.dialog-page").click(function)
$(document).on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function);

If yes , use the second one only

Comment: If thats not the issue still, could you please add a fiddle link so that we can check ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#dynamic-id').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
    event.preventDefault;
    $this = $(this);

          var URL     = $(this).attr('href');
          var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialog');
          var dialogOptions = {

                        width: 500,
                        height: 200,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function(event, ui){
                            $('#dialog').empty(); 
                       }
          };

    if(dialogbox==null) {
        $this.after("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");

    }

    jQuery('#dialog').load(URL + " #content").dialog(dialogOptions);
});
```

**Reason for not working** -

```
$("a.dialog-page").click(function(event) {
```

and

```
$('#dynamic-id').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){
```

are basically the same. so when you are executing the second line you are overriding the previous `onclick` event. You can use any one of them and you should be just fine. Here is the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/KytV8/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to target an element that exists on pageload and use the on() function

```
$('#container').on('click', '.element', function(){ });
```

The way you were originally trying to do it, the click listener doesn't get set since when it's applied, it can't find the element it's trying to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are defining the click event statically, which will never be triggered by the A tag since it's not being attached to the dynamic content, then defining and attaching a new click after the dynamic data is loaded that only stops the event. I would change it to this, as also alluded to by Pointy's comment:

```
<div id="dynamic-id">
  <a class="dialog-page" href="/test/test.php">Link to test</a>
</div>

$('#dynamic-id').on('click', 'a.dialog-page', function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
          $this = $(this);

          var URL     = $(this).attr('href');
          var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialog');
          var dialogOptions = {

                        width: 500,
                        height: 200,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function(event, ui){
                            $('#dialog').empty(); 
                       }
          };

    if(dialogbox==null) {
        $this.after("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");

    }

    jQuery('#dialog').load(URL + " #content").dialog(dialogOptions);
  });
```